# Deploy Django to Heroku - Push rejected

Tags: django, git, deployment, heroku

Estoy intentando desplegar en Heroku una aplicación Django. Cuando yo ejecuto el comando `git push heroku master` aparece lo siguiente:

```
(uleague) ➜ pickapp git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (195/195), 516.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 195 (delta 93), reused 195 (delta 93)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote: to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/a...
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to shielded-crag-57385.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shielde...
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielde...
(uleague) ➜ pickapp git:(master) ✗
```

Yo tengo la siguiente estructura  de directorios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado siguiendo [la guia de Getting Started
 en Heroku para Python y Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app) y en ella se entiende que hay un archivo `requirements.txt` pero no una carpeta requirements/base.txt/development.txt

Sera que esto tiene algo que ver?
Dado que cuando efectúo el push, lo primero por lo que se empieza es el proceso de instalación de las dependnecias.

¿Tendría esto relación con mi error?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He eliminado el directorio requirements/ que tenía en la raíz de mi proyecto Django y creado un solo archivo requirements.txt en la raíz de mi proyecto Django y obtengo el mismo resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git (push)
origin  https://bgarcial@bitbucket.org/bgarcial/pickapp.git (fetch)
origin  https://bgarcial@bitbucket.org/bgarcial/pickapp.git (push)
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (195/195), 516.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 195 (delta 93), reused 195 (delta 93)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fuupbol.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git'
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗
```

También intenté dejar mi directorio requirements/ y tener un requirements.txt en mi raíz y ahi decirle que -r requirements/production.txt el cual llama al base.txt (con la estructura de directorios presentada de primero en esta pregunta) y tampoco obtuve resultados, fue el mismo error.

No se si esté haciendo lo correcto.

Comment: Intentaste correr la app localmente con [Run the app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally)?

Comment: Si, localmente me despliega, parece ser que requirements si debe ir en la raíz y no bajo una carpeta y distribuido acorde al tipo de despliegue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces push a heroku, lo que hace heroku es buscar un buildpack que pueda entender la aplicación que estás deployando, para eso se ejecuta el archivo detect de cada buildpack y el primero que tiene éxito es el que se asigna como buildpack de tu aplicación.

En el caso de python el [detect](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect) busca el archivo requirements.txt o el archivo setup.py, si ninguno de esos archivos está, heroku considera que tu proyecto no es python y sigue probando.

Tendrías que agregar uno de esos archivos en el root de tu aplicación.

Comment: mira mi **ACTUALIZACIÓN** la cual la he adicionado en la pregunta por favor. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo men.

Comment: también intente crear o tener en cuenta el buildpack al momento de crear la aplicación, y obtuve el mismo error sin importar si tengo a requirements.txt en la raiz o no http://pastebin.com/raw/mpZKnHuS En esta pregunta se detalla como lo hago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089754/deploy-django-to-heroku-push-rejected, ver **UPDATE 1**

Comment: Este es el actual estado de mi deployment de heroku por si de pronto tienes el espacio de poder revisar y orienmtarme un poco. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6541/deploy-static-assets-to-heroku-from-local-machine-cant-open-file-manage-py

Comment: En esta pregunta que he contestado, esta el procedimiento de principio a fin de como desplegar una aplicación Django en Heroku. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6541/deploy-static-assets-to-heroku-from-local-machine-cant-open-file-manage-py

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es tener tu archivo `requirements.txt` como lo habías pensado, en la raíz del proyecto, con el siguiente contenido:

```
# Este archivo es el que espera Heroku.

-r requirements/production.txt
```

Luego, como vez ahí, ese archivo apunta al archivo `production.txt` de la carpeta `/requirements/` de la raíz del proyecto que es la que se va a terminar ejecutando cuando se lance en producción desde Heroku.

A su vez, dentro de la carpeta `/requirements/` puedes tener distintos archivos según tu entorno, por ejemplo

```
requirements/
    --> base.txt
    --> local.txt
    --> production.txt
    --> test.txt
```

En los cuales vas a ir especificando los paquetes para cada entorno.

Luego, `production.txt` puede contener lo siguiente, por ejemplo

```
# /requirements/production.txt

-r ./base.txt

gunicorn==19.8.1  # https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn
psycopg2==2.7.4 --no-binary psycopg2  # https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2
whitenoise==4.1.2 # http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/
dj-database-url==0.5.0 # https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/
```

Como se ve, en mi caso, llama primero a `base.txt`, instala todos los paquetes por defecto, y luego instala los necesarios para producción.

Hay otra cuestión también que podrías tener en cuenta también, para un desarrollo e implementación más ameno:

- Separar la configuración de desarrollo y la de producción dividiendo el archivo `settings.py` en varios archivos. [Aquí](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html) una excelente explicación de como hacerlo.